# Symfony DQuery builder: Magic method doesn't select the right table

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, query-builder

I have 2 entity :
`teacher`, `subject` with a ManyTo One Relation

`(subject many--- one teacher)`, which created me a 3rd table `subject_teacher`

I have a form to create a Teacher, and a form to create a Subject, where i can choose the teacher from an option list. 
For each subject, I want to retrieve each teachers datas (firstname last name, the name of the subject he's teaching). 1 teacher can teach more than 1 subjects.

In my controller, i'm doing :

`$teachers = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Teacher')->findAll();
 $subject = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Subject')->findByTeachers($teachers);`

but i'm getting error :

`An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.name AS name_2 FROM subject t0 WHERE subject_teacher.teacher_id IN (?, ?, ?)' with params [49, 50, 51]:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'subject_teacher.teacher_id' in 'where clause'`

The magic method `findByTeachers` forgot to add the table `subject_teacher` in the `FROM` clause ?
Or i did something wrong..

Subject entity :

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Subject
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\Repository\SubjectRepository")
 */
class Subject
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Teacher", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $teachers;

/**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Event", mappedBy="subject", cascade={"persist"})
*/
private $events;


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set name
 *
 * @param string $name
 *
 * @return Subject
 */
public function setName($name)
{
    $this->name = $name;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get name
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getName()
{
    return $this->name;
}

/**
 * Set classclassRoom
 *
 * @param integer $classRoom
 *
 * @return Subject
 */
public function setClassRoom($classRoom)
{
    $this->classRoom = $classRoom;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get classRoom
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getClassRoom()
{
    return $this->classRoom;
}

/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->events = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    $this->teachers = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * Add event
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Event $event
 *
 * @return Subject
 */
public function addEvent(\AppBundle\Entity\Event $event)
{
    $this->events[] = $event;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove event
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Event $event
 */
public function removeEvent(\AppBundle\Entity\Event $event)
{
    $this->events->removeElement($event);
}

/**
 * Get events
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getEvents()
{
    return $this->events;
}

/**
 * Get teachers
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getTeachers()
{
    return $this->teachers;
}

/**
 * Add teacher
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Teacher $teacher
 *
 * @return Subject
 */
public function addTeacher(\AppBundle\Entity\Teacher $teacher)
{
    $this->teachers[] = $teacher;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove teacher
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Teacher $teacher
 */
public function removeTeacher(\AppBundle\Entity\Teacher $teacher)
{
    $this->teachers->removeElement($teacher);
}
```

}

Teacher entity :
    `

```
 namespace AppBundle\Entity;

 use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

 /**
  * Teacher
  *
  * @ORM\Table()
  * @ORM\Entity
  */
 class Teacher
 {
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="firstName", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $firstName;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="lastName", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $lastName;


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set firstName
 *
 * @param string $firstName
 *
 * @return Teacher
 */
public function setFirstName($firstName)
{
    $this->firstName = $firstName;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get firstName
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getFirstName()
{
    return $this->firstName;
}

/**
 * Set lastName
 *
 * @param string $lastName
 *
 * @return Teacher
 */
public function setLastName($lastName)
{
    $this->lastName = $lastName;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get lastName
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getLastName()
{
    return $this->lastName;
}
}
`
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit, i was struggling...

Comment: What do you really want to do? Do you really need 2 query?

Comment: I edited my post with my needs, thanks. Maybe i don't need 2 queries, but with 1 it doesn't work neither. If i only do `$subjects = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Subject')->findAll();` i have my subjects but i can't access teachers data

Comment: It seems that `teacher` & `subject` have a Many To Many relation

Comment: And this isn't a good thing ? I did many to One,i get rid of the first error, but when i try to add a new subject with 1 or 2 teachers, i have this : `Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to AppBundle\Entity\Subject::setTeachers() must be an instance of AppBundle\Entity\Teacher, instance of Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection given, called in /home/marvin/planning/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/PropertyAccess/PropertyAccessor.php on line 442 and defined  `

Comment: This error was because my form had a multiple fields. Now my `$teachers = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Teacher')->findAll();
 $subject = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Subject')->findByTeachers($teachers);` works....but when i'm adding a subject, i can't choose more than 1 teacher. Thanks for pointing out my manyTOMany issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I you want to retrieve all the Teacher "data" for each subject:

```
/**** CONTROLLER ****/

$subjects = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Subject')->findAll();


//If you need to threat results inside the controller:

$results = [];

foreach ($subjects as $subject) {
     $results[]['name'] = $subject->getName();
     $results[]['teacher_fistname'] = $subject->getTeachers()->getFirstName();
     $results[]['teacher_lastname'] = $subject->getTeachers()->getLastName();
    /.../
}

return $results;





// If you only want to display results in the view:

return $this->render('your-template.html.twig', ['subjects' => $subjects ]);

/**** And in the view ****/

{% for subject in subjects %}
  Subject: {{ subject.name }}
  Teacher Fistname: {{ subject.teachers.firstname }}
  Teacher Lastname: {{ subject.teachers.lastname }}
  /.../

{% endfor%}
```

Comment: Thanks
i have this error : `Attempted to call an undefined method named "getFirstName" of class "Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection". ` But i have getFirstname...

Comment: A dump of ŝubjects->getTeachers give me that: 

`SubjectController.php on line 27:
PersistentCollection {#451 ▼
  -snapshot: []
  -owner: Subject {#434 ▼
    -id: 1
    -name: "Subject1aezeaze"
    -teachers: PersistentCollection {#451}
    -events: PersistentCollection {#478 ▶}
  }
  -association: array:20 [ …20]
  -em: EntityManager {#142 …11}
  -backRefFieldName: null
  -typeClass: ClassMetadata {#436 …}
  -isDirty: false
  #collection: ArrayCollection {#450 ▶}
  #initialized: false
}`

Comment: i had to add another foreach: 
`foreach ($subject->getTeachers() as $teacher){

             $results[]['teacher_firstname'] = $teacher->getFirstName();
             $results[]['teacher_lastname'] = $teacher->getLastName();
        }`

Thanks i'll be back quiclky

Comment: same in twig `                    {% for subject in subjects %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{subject.name}}</td>
                        {% for teacher in subject.teachers %}
                            <td>{{ teacher.firstName }}</td>
                            <td>{{ teacher.lastName }}</td>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </tr>
                    {% endfor %}`
And it works great ! thanks you so much!